# Python TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Tags: python

```
class Weapon:

    def equipItem(self, playerTruename, itemTruename):
        if isinstance(itemTruename, Weapon):
            do blah blah
```

I don't really get this one. arg2 in isinstance() can be a class too, right? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; please add enough code to reproduce the error, and show the full error message. You can edit your question to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: a class *is* a `type`. Note, `type` is just a *constructor* for `type` objects, i.e. class objects. You can think of a class definition statement `class Foo(Bar): ...` as syntactic sugar for `Foo = type('Foo', (Bar,), namespace)`. So, *this should work* assuming `Weapon` is a class i.e. a type. You must provide a [mcve] for us to diagnose a problem, though

Answer (score 0):

Try:
isinstance(itemTruename, type(Weapon)):

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in the following code:

```
class Weapon:

    def equipItem(self, playerTruename, itemTruename):
        if isinstance(itemTruename, Weapon):
            print(playerTruename)

w = Weapon()
w.equipItem('x', w)
```

Prints `x`.